# Advanced Search Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I Try to build Advanced Search by Name and/or Category and/or Location and/or Month but i have issues i can't fix it, this the controller;

```
$searchName = $advancedSearchData['search_name'];
$searchCategory = $advancedSearchData['search_category'];
$searchLocation = $advancedSearchData['search_location'];

        if(!empty($searchName)) {
            $allCourses = Courses::where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> get();
        }

        if($searchCategory !== 0) {
            $allCourses = Courses::where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['category_id' => $searchLocation]) -> get();
        }

        if($coursesLocation !== 0) {
            $allCourses = Courses::where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['location' => $searchLocation]) -> get();
        }

return view('layouts.public_layouts.courses.courses_search') -> with(compact('allCourses'));
```

Comment: What are the issues you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$allCourses = Courses::where(function($query) use ($advancedSearchData) {
                    if(isset($advancedSearchData['search_name'])){
                        $query->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$advancedSearchData['search_name'].'%');
                    }
                    if(isset($advancedSearchData['search_category']))){
                        $query->where(['category_id' => $advancedSearchData['search_category']);
                    }
                    if(isset($advancedSearchData['search_location']))){
                        $query->where(['location' => $advancedSearchData['search_location']);
                    }
                })
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I don't know what exactly the issue is but I can see the issue. In a advanced search you must use `->get()` at the end of the code. In this way you can add any condition to your query before execution.

```
$allCourses = new Course();
$allCourses = $allCourses->newQuery();

$searchName = $advancedSearchData['search_name'];
$searchCategory = $advancedSearchData['search_category'];
$searchLocation = $advancedSearchData['search_location'];

if(!empty($searchName)) {
$allCourses = $allCourses->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%');
}

if($searchCategory !== 0) {
$allCourses = $allCourses->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['category_id' => $searchLocation]);
}

if($coursesLocation !== 0) {
$allCourses = $allCourses->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['location' => $searchLocation]);
}

$allCourses = $allCourses->get();

return view('layouts.public_layouts.courses.courses_search') -> with(compact('allCourses'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you will face is undefined index so you must check on the array indexes first like:

```
 $searchName     = $advancedSearchData['search_name'] ?? null;
 $searchCategory = $advancedSearchData['search_category'] ?? null;
 $searchLocation = $advancedSearchData['search_location'] ?? null;

 $query = (new Course())->newQuery();

 if($searchName) {
        $query->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%');
    }

 if($searchCategory) {
        $query->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['category_id' => $searchLocation]);
    }

 if($coursesLocation) {
        $query->where('course_name', 'like', '%'.$searchName.'%') -> where(['location' => $searchLocation]);
    }

$allCourses = $query->get();

return view('layouts.public_layouts.courses.courses_search')->with(compact('allCourses'));
```